# Preposition before a university study

Tags: prepositions

> In college, I was more interested in chemistry and maths - that's why I decided to go to study in pharmacy.

Is this sentence correct? Or should I use "with" before "pharmacy"?

Comment: Don't use a preposition there; 'was studying in chemistry' is probably archaic.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 'with' or 'in'. The right way to say it is

> I decided to study pharmacy